# Why is only one of these (nearly) identical demos getting stuck in a loop?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, infinite-loop, jquery-events

I have been fighting with the weirdest loop. I simplified my code down to these two NEARLY IDENTICAL jsFiddles.

1. http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/crzTB/5/ (infinite loop)
2. http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/crzTB/7/ (runs as I expected)

One of them gets stuck in a loop (open your console). One of them does not.

The only difference is a class name. Seriously, open them in two tabs and go back and fourth. They're identical.

I've tested this in Chrome, Firefox and IE on multiple computers, varying which one I open first. Same result every time. Why??????????????

```
$("body").on("keydown", ".fixedValue:not(input)", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("the div (which is not input?) was triggered.");

    $(".fixedValue input").trigger("keydown", e.keyCode);
});

$(".fixedValue input").on("keydown", function (e) {
    console.log("input (e.g. not the div) triggered.");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JayC said, the reason the one doesn't recurse is because you didn't change all instances of the class name. To fix your actual problem, try this:

```
$(".fixedValue input").on("keydown", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("input (e.g. not the div) triggered.");
});
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/crzTB/8/).

The keydown event was bubbling to the parent div and then getting triggered again on the child.

Comment: Oh, I had preventDefault and stopPropigation mixed up in my mind. I'm doubly dumb today.

Answer (score 3):

The one that doesn't get stuck in a loop does not have an input within some item with class `fixedValue`, so there's no input to be triggered.

Comment: In other words, the one that isn't getting stuck you aren't calling .myClass, you're still calling .fixedValue so you're only seeing one call to console.